# How to get Dataframe with Table ID in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract dataframe from HTML using URL.

- The page contains 59 table/dataframe.
- I want to extract 1 particular table which can be identified by its ID "ctl00_Menu1"

Following is my trail which is giving error.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS12.htm?st=S12",attrs = {'id': 'ctl00_Menu1'})
```

[image]

As this is my very early stage in python so can be simple solution but I am unable to find. appreciate help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Have you tried doing simply `list_of_dfs = pd.read_html("http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS12.htm?st=S12")`? This should give you a list of dataframes which you can access by index, iterate over or reshape easily.

Comment: @ayorgo Edited my question. In the given url, the HTML contains 59 table/dataframe. I want to extract single dataframe with id attribute of table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at how the URL passes params and probably try to read a dataframe directly from it. I'm unsure if you are trying to develop a function or a script or just exercising.

If you do (notice the 58 at the end of the url)

```
df = pd.read_html("http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS12.htm?st=S1258",attrs = {'id': 
'ctl00_Menu1'})
```

It works and gives you table 59.

```
[                                  0          1   2  \
 0                         Partywise  Partywise NaN   
 1                         Partywise        NaN NaN   
 2  Constituencywise-All  Candidates        NaN NaN   
 3           Constituencywise Trends        NaN NaN   

                                   3                                 4   5  \
 0  Constituencywise-All  Candidates  Constituencywise-All  Candidates NaN   
 1                               NaN                               NaN NaN   
 2                               NaN                               NaN NaN   
 3                               NaN                               NaN NaN   

                          6                        7  
 0  Constituencywise Trends  Constituencywise Trends  
 1                      NaN                      NaN  
 2                      NaN                      NaN  
 3                      NaN                      NaN  ]
```

Unsure if that's the table you want to extract, but most of the time it's easier to pass it as a url parameter. If you try it without the 58 it works too, I believe the 'ElectionResult' argument might not be a table classifier hence why you can't find any tables with that name.